# Query MongoDB with mongoose and return an array of string matching one of the keys of the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema and would love to query my database for all products for example where the seller matches foo, and return only the categories in a string array. how do I achieve this using mongoose?

````
  seller: {
    type: String
  },
  category: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: String
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
});


const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productsSchema);```
````

Comment: input sample docs & required o/p will help much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I tested a few methods and I found this to work very well;

```
app.get("/shop", (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.params.roomID);

    Product.find({room: req.params.roomID}, (error, doc) => {

      const categoryArray = doc.map(newArray => newArray.category);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOne function in the following form

```
const stringArray = await Product.find({seller:'foo'},{category:1});
```